# Guidance on time-series change point detection or identification of contributions

Tags: time-series, bayesian, gaussian-process, change-point

*Let me preface this by saying that I am not a data scientist. Please excuse any imprecision in my use of subject specific terms or notations. Please feel free to edit my question, to improve any ambiguity.*

**Plain English problem description:**

I am using an analogy to describe my problem, to keep to description comprehensible.

Let's assume I measure the amount of water pouring out of a pipe. Lets also assume, the pipe is fed from multiple (hidden) sources where each contributes a set amount. Any individual source may be active or inactive at any given point in time. Depending on which sources are currently active, more or less water will pour out at the end.

Given only the water output at the end, I am trying to identify:

- how many individual sources there are in total (that can contribute in theory)
- how much each individual source contributes if it is active
- which sources are active at a given point in time.

---

**Attempt to formalize the problem:**

I have a time-series dataset $X_t$ generated by a random process that is the addition of $N$ normal distributions ("sources").

$$X_t \sim \sum_{i}^{N}\textbf{1}_{i,t}\,\,\mathcal{N}(\mu_i,\,\sigma_i^{2})$$

where $\textbf{1}_{i,t} = \begin{cases}
1 &\text{if source } i \text{ is active at time } t \\
0 &\text{if source } i \text{ is not active at time } t
\end{cases}$

Assumptions:

- At any point in time, typically only a small number of individual "sources" are active: $\sum_{i}^{N}\textbf{1}_{i,t} \ll N \quad \forall\,t$
- The frequency of change of the activity of individual sources is small compared to the sampling frequency of $X_t$. I.e. the value of $\textbf{1}_{i,t}$ does not change very often.
- $\mu_i \gg \sigma_i \quad \forall\,i$

Given the dataset $X_t = \{x_0, x_1, ..., x_t\}$, I am trying to determine:

- How many sources $N$ have been active at one point or another in the dataset. I.e. determine the best estimate of the value of $N$.
- For a given point in time $t$, which of the sources were active at that point. (And what their individual $\mu_i$ are.)

If this is a standard problem with a well known solution, could you please let me know its name to allow me to research it further?

If this is not a well-known problem, could you provide some keywords to help guide my literature research?

Of course recommendations for any papers or books or advice on a solution strategy would be much appreciated as well.

---

**Current solution strategy:**

At present my thought is that I could use a change point detection algorithm to segment the time series and go from there. But I am sure there are more suitable approaches.

Am I with the keyword "gaussian process" on the right track here?

Comment: I guess $\mathbf{1}_{i,t}$ are correlated over time? Could you describe in plain English what is your data?

Comment: @Tim My application does not lend itself to plain english descriptions. I did however add a plain English description of an analogous problem to the question. Does this help answer your question regarding my problem?

Comment: Your proposed model does not account for "how much each individual source contributes if it is active" since you assign equal weights to them (1 or 0). Also, I guess we can assume some correlation over time?

Comment: @Tim No, the "weights" as you call them only indicate whether a source $i$ is active or not. The mean contribution of source $i$ is $\mu_i$. Yes you can assume correlation since: _The frequency of change of the activity of individual sources is small compared to the sampling frequency $X_i$._ The time series is thus autocorrelated - at least within a given time window.

Comment: Then by such definition of the model you answered one of your questions: each source has the same influence, since they have equal weights.

Comment: @Tim I cannot follow your argument. It would imply that $\mu_i = \mu_j \quad\forall i\not =j$. That not an assumption I detailed and it should not be implied since in this case I simply would have used $\mu$ without subscript source index.

Comment: I think a change point detection algorithm sounds like a great idea here. Since all the means are positive then we can simply say that a source was turned off if we estimate a decline in the flow, and that one was turned on if we observe an increase in the flow. Assuming that you want to detect the changes retrospectively, rather than detecting changes as they occur, the PELT algorithm is probably best for offline unless you have some other good algorithm already implemented. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1101.1438.pdf